# Use a Java Package Across Several Projects Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

As I do more and more coding in Java I am creating a library of methods that I use often. Is there a way in Eclipse to set it so that I can import these methods from the source folder of the library project to other projects without copying them to each individual project?

I know there is something that I can do with the Build Path, but when I try to add the source for my library I get a package error in the project it is linked to.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't import/copy the code from another project--the point is to use the *output* of the shared project. Just indicate that the project depends on the other project; don't think about the shared project's source.

Comment: How do I go about indicating that the project depends on the other project. I know I want to share the output between the projects, but don't know how so, so far I have just been copying the package.

Comment: Never mind figured it out.
When setting up the build path use the project tab to select the project you want to share.

Is there away to set this as a default so it automatically does it for all future projects?